# Scipy, odeint and setting of input into odeint input function

Tags: python, function, scipy, ode

I am integrating biochemical ODEs via odeint (see pic below), however the main input function seems to be re-setting (or replacing) the input parameters with strange numbers when called. Despite the fact that the parameters 'iu' (rate of induction of v, should stay constant over whole process) and 'v' (one of results, should change throughout odeint) are set to 100 and 0 respectively, if printed throughout the function, the output seems to be:

```
'0.000999900009999 100 0 0 10 9 2 2 3'
```

while it should look more like this:

```
'0 0 0 100 10 9 2 2 3'
```

I am unsure about whether the error is in my initial function, or in my implementation of odeint: first time doing this kind of things, however I find it strange that the switch_a function just ignores the preset inputs: any ideas on how to resolve this/what could have gone wrong? I already attempted to seed the function manually from the inside, however as at least one of the inputs (v) should be changing during the course of odeint, this will not do.

```
initial = np.array([0,0])#sets initial
#parameters
iv = 0
iu= 100
u = 0
v = 0
au = 10
av = 9
b=2
n=2
k=3


def switch_a(initial, timepool, u, v, iv, iu , au , av ,b , n , k ):
zu = (1+iv/k)**n #to simplify equation
zv = (1+ iu/k)**n
u = -u + (au/(1+((v/zu)**b)))
print (u, v, iv, iu, au, av, b, n, k)
v = -v + (av/(1+((u/zv)**b)))
res = np.array([u, v])
return res

args = (iv, iu, u, v, au, av, b, n, k)
timepool = np.linspace (1, 50, 50)
solution1a = sp.odeint (switch_a, initial, timepool,args)
```

[image: Function]

Comment: The format of the ODE function is `derivs(state, time, params)`, where `time` is really a single time, not the full list of times that you want samples from in the solution. If you at some point use the time in the ODE function, this more precise naming might help to get a better intuition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that u and v are your dynamical variables in this system of equation, they're supposed to go into the first argument to your `switch_a` function, and not into later arguments. I think this may be closer to what you're looking to do:

```
def switch_a(variables, timepool, iv, iu , au , av ,b , n , k ):
    u, v = variables
    zu = (1+iv/k)**n #to simplify equation
    zv = (1+ iu/k)**n
    u2 = -u + (au/(1+((v/zu)**b)))
    print (u, v, iv, iu, au, av, b, n, k)
    v2 = -v + (av/(1+((u/zv)**b)))
    res = np.array([u2, v2])
    return res

args = (iv, iu, au, av, b, n, k)
timepool = np.linspace (1, 50, 50)
solution1a = sp.odeint (switch_a, initial, timepool, args)
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct: the function seems to work in this form! Thanks!